# How to create logout without SQL and only PHP?

Tags: php, html

So far, I have only the login.html files which has login form, redirects user once logged on and logout function. What I want to do is once a user logs in, they redirect to  but their username is displayed on the top of the page. And with the  file... I just want it to be able to logout the user. So far on my website, I can login as far as I am concerned, and it redirects once user logs in, but I can login as many times as I want, and I can logout as many times as I want.... It's complicated to sort out and I want to do this without SQL or any other server-side storage (since I am only using HTML local storage).

Comment: Why do you need to log in if you don't want to use any server-side storage?  Why does logging in matter?

Comment: Use PHP to prevent displaying the login form.  Also, use PHP to prevent someone from logging in *again* if they are already logged in.  `if ( $_SESSION['username'] ) {  //... redirect / show "already logged in" message };`

Comment: Well look, i literally just want the user to be able to log in, and once they are logged in, their username is displayed on the homepage... and i want a logout button to be displayed so once it's clicked, the user logs out..

Comment: Can anyone alter my current codes and show me how it is done, i just want to know, because i am clueless in going forward with this

Comment: @A.Adams in your Gamewebsite.php page (where you finally redirect after successful login), just echo out `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: What you are doing is to store the username in a session and deleting it. any user can enter the same name and php cannot cross check sessions. you have to have a server side storage to set and clear a "logged in" flag.

Comment: Note that each request (log  in) is a separate and isolated process on the server side. you have to have a common place to check the user log in status.

Comment: Okay in that case, can anyone show me how to do this?? What codes shall i show you: the registration code?

Comment: Install an sql server, create a "users" table with "id, username, loggedin" columns. Every time a user log in check if the loggedin flag is false, if true then the user is already logged in. if False, toggle it to true.

Comment: Start with installing the sql and writing some php to read and write to db and then come back again with the code and questions. I didn't mention registration and passwords because they weren't requirements in your question.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter i have tried to echo that out but it says "Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\GameWebsite.php on line 2"

Comment: @A.Adams you need to post the code that actually throws the error.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter ::: <?php 
echo $_SESSION["username"];
?>

Comment: @A.Adams did you do `session_start()` before that line?

Comment: Okay yes that was my mistake, but if i was to logout, how would i make that disappear so the user knows they've logged out

Comment: @A.Adams Add a test to the top of your gamewebsite.php file that tests if username is set in `$_SESSION` - if not, redirect to your login page because they are not logged in.

Comment: Would you kindly show me how that is achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WRITE THIS ALL IN TOP PAGE

IN YOUR LOGIN PAGE

```
       <?php
        session_start();
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $username = $_POST["username"];
            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

        header('Refresh: 5; URL=GameWebsite.php')
        }
        ?>
```

IN YOUR LOGOUT PAGE

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
  session_start();
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  //Then you may redirect to the login page if you want after sometime.
  echo " You have successfully logged out... You will be redirected back to the login page in a moment. ";
 header('Refresh: 5; URL=login.php'); 
    }
     else
    {
       header("Location:login.php"); // HERE WHEN USER NO HAVE SESSION
    }
```

IN ANOTHER PAGES YOU CHECK

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{

}else
{
 header("Location:login.php"); // HERE WHEN USER NO HAVE SESSION
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the session of username in logout code

```
unset($_SESSION['username']);
```

Hope this helps..If not,It would be better if you could provide the code, so that the problem can be sorted out

Answer (score 0):

in your login page write on top

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
header('Refresh: 5; URL=GameWebsite.html')
}
```

In your logout.php write

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
   session_start();
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  //Then you may redirect to the login page if you want after sometime.
  echo " You have successfully logged out... You will be redirected back to the login page in a moment. ";
 header('Refresh: 5; URL=Login.html'); 
    }
     else
    {
       header("Location: login.php");
    }
```

Comment: when you loged in only that time you can see  logout button 
you can check it like this 
`<?php isset($_SESSION['username']{?>`
`HERE YOUR LOGOUT BUTTON`
`<?php}?>`
When user click on logout button he redirect into logout php and int ther he see your message

Comment: <?php isset($_SESSION['username'] { ?>
<a href="logout.php" style="position:absolute;top:120px;right:35px "> Click here to logout </a>
<?php } ?>

Comment: what you have in that line?

Comment: <?php isset($_SESSION['username'] { ?> <a href="logout.php" style="position:absolute;top:120px;right:35px "> Click here to logout </a> <?php } ?>

Comment: can you send me 3 files login logout and GameWebsite php ?

Comment: how can i send?

Comment: webintervale@gmail.com

Comment: past it on line
`<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?> <a href="logout.php" style="position:absolute;top:120px;right:35px "> Click here to logout </a> <?php } ?>`

Comment: Sorry, paste what on that line?

Comment: Replace line 84

`<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?> <a href="logout.php" style="position:absolute;top:120px;right:35px "> Click here to logout </a> <?php } ?>`

Comment: Okay, how are you sure that this button, when clicked, actually logs the user out?

Comment: Yes you can check it

Comment: Okay well when i click that logout button, i am aware that it sends me to login.php which is in the else statement in logout.php file. So that means it isnt logged out?

Comment: in your every file you must check you have $_SESSION['username'] or no If you have not $_SESSION['username'] you must redirect that guest into login page if you have you can show that page and when you destroy your  $_SESSION you automaticly redirect login page. write function what check  user is loged in or no and put it into your header

Comment: is this correct <?php 
session_start(); 
if($_SESSION["username"]){
echo $_SESSION["username"];}
else{
 header("Location: login.php");
}
?>

Comment: the logout function doesn't really work because when i go back to GameWebsite.php after logging out... the user's username is still displayed on the top of the GameWebsite.php.. this indicates user is logged in?

Comment: No like this
`if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
DO SOMETHIN
}
ELSE
{
DO SOMETHING
}`

Comment: Nothing works... your suggestion didn't help mate... anyways